# Finding two one dimensional subvector spaces with same image

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find two differenf subvector spaces of $\mathbb{Z}_7^3$, that have same image under linear transformation $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}_7^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_7^2$ with $v \mapsto A \cdot v$.

A is given as $\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 1 & 5\\ 
0 & 2 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

One of them is probably simply <$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c
\end{pmatrix}$> which gives us $\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c\end{pmatrix} \cdot A^t = \begin{pmatrix}
4a+b+5c & 2b+c 
\end{pmatrix}$.

I suppose we have to modify a in the first subspace, in such a way that the result would still be (or at least congruent mod 7) the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
4a+b+5c & 2b+c 
\end{pmatrix}$. How to do this?

Comment: Find a basis for the kernel. Extend it to a basis for the domain. Now delete the vector in the kernel, and you are left with a basis for a 2-dimensional subspace whose image is the same as the image of the whole, 3-dimensional space.

Comment: I have it. basis of kernel is in this example (1 1 6), so we have to extend it by (0 0 1), I suppose.

I forgot to add that both searched subvector spaces should be one dimensional, so myy purposed solution above doesnt work.

Comment: Good. Now that you have it, write it up and post it as a solution. Then, after a while, you can accept it. This helps clear up the Unanswered Questions list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions are:
 $U_1 = \left\{ (0,0,1)^t \right\} $ and  $U_2 = \left\{ (1,1,0)^t \right\} $. They are both clearly one dimensional (their size is 1) and have the same image, namely: $(5, 2)^t$.